# How to unmarshall `x-www-form-urlencoded` data with the functional web framework?

Tags: java, spring

I'm using the functional web framework for a non-reactive application. Consuming JSON seems simple enough as `request.body(FormModel.class)`

However, when the data is `x-www-form-urlencoded`, I'm trying

```java
    default RouterFunction<ServerResponse> submit() {
        return RouterFunctions.route(POST(submitRoute()),request -> {
            var request.body(new ParameterizedTypeReference<FormModel>() {});

            return temporaryRedirect(allRoute()).build();
        });
    }
```

And I'm getting:

`Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported`

Using MVC, this would work just by declaring a `FormModel` parameter and annotating it with `@ModelAttribute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, "binding" is not the same as "converting" for Spring, and the systems involved are different. There's no easy way of getting binding to work with router functions. There's an [open issue about it](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25943) targeting Spring 6. As per the workaround given there, my code would work with

```java
    default RouterFunction<ServerResponse> submit() {
        return RouterFunctions.route(POST(submitRoute()).and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)), request -> {
            var form = formService().emptyForm();
            var binder = new ExtendedServletRequestDataBinder(form, "editing");
            binder.bind(request.servletRequest());

            return temporaryRedirect(allRoute()).build();
        });
    }
```

Note that you have to get an empty `FormModel` instance from somewhere. It's not the best, but it works.